# JAALEE Beacon SDK not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am using iBeacons manufactured by JAALEE, Liam trying get list go iBeacons near to me but i am not able to get it

```
//  JLEConfigBeacon.m
//  Example
//
//  Created by jaalee on 14-4-23.
//  Copyright (c) 2014年 jaalee. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BeaconList.h"
#import "JLEBeaconDevice.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "PetFinderViewController.h"
#import "AdvertisementViewController.h"

@interface BeaconList ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mBeaconDeviceList;
@property (nonatomic) JLEBeaconConfigManager *mBeaconConfigManager;
@property (nonatomic) JLEBeaconDevice *mBeaconDevice;

@end

@implementation BeaconList
@synthesize destinationName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _mBeaconDeviceList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _mBeaconConfigManager = [[JLEBeaconConfigManager alloc] init];
    _mBeaconConfigManager.delegate = self;

    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    if ([[self title] isEqualToString:@"Beacon List"]) {
        [self setTitle:@"Pet Finder"];
    }
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_mBeaconDeviceList removeAllObjects];
    [self.mTableView reloadData];
    [_mBeaconConfigManager startJaaleeBeaconsDiscovery];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark - JLEBeaconConfigManager delegate

- (void)beaconConfigManager:(JLEBeaconConfigManager *)manager didDiscoverBeacon:(JLEBeaconDevice *)beacon RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    for (int i = 0; i < _mBeaconDeviceList.count; i++) {
        JLEBeaconDevice *temp = [_mBeaconDeviceList objectAtIndex:i];
        if (temp == beacon) {
            return;
        }
    }

    [_mBeaconDeviceList addObject:beacon];
    [self.mTableView reloadData];
}


@end
```

Dont know how to resolve this. i want to use this to get Proximity UUID from detected beacon.

[GIT LINK OF SDK](https://github.com/jaalee/Jaalee-Beacon-iOS-SDK-master)

Comment: I did the down vote. My question are:  Is `prepareForSegue:sender` code relevant to your question ? Is the whole UITableView/Delegate/DataSource methods relevant to your question ? Is the commented part "Navigation" relevant ? Where does your app goes? `startJaaleeBeaconsDiscovery`says: "Start beacon discovery process based on CoreBluetooth framework. Method is useful for older beacons discovery that are not advertising as iBeacons." Is that your case?

Comment: i did post whole .m file for better understanding.

Comment: i have removed extra code upvote now

Answer (score 0):

If you ibeacon do not have any additional features as estimote ibeacons(accelerometers and temperature sensor), you must not use SDK.

Look at this tutorial for iOS 8 and change the UUID.

http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14279747-tutorial-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8

Comment: solution is not useful for me